# South database adapter missing in django project when migrate in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, migration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk instance, when I put the command

```
02_migrate:
  command: "django-admin.py migrate"
  leader_only: true
```

It fails with the following message:

`[Instance: i-xxxxxx] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: There is no South database module 'south.db.postgresql_psycopg2' for your database. Please either choose a supported database, check for SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER[S] settings, or remove South from INSTALLED_APPS. container_command 02_migrate in .ebextensions/myproject.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.`

At localhost I don't have any trouble migrating. I'm using django 1.8 so there no South needed. Even in requirements.txt South is not present, neither in settings.py. I read in similar threads that uninstall South solves the problem, but South is not installed.

Having a 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.1 running Python 2.7.

I tried with a clean initial and --fake-initial migrate without success.

Comment: EBS = Elastic Block Store. EB = Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: looks like you're using django 1.7 - can you add a version echo to your ebextension to find out?

Comment: I think I found the problem. There was a python package that installs South and I didn't figure it out. I had to ssh the EC2 instance to manually delete South from the venv. The next EB deployment everything succeded

Comment: @po5i make sure you wrap this deletion in a .ebextension, or the next time EB will spin a host up you'll face the same issue

Comment: @Tal I don't think so because next time the django-paypal package will be installed with a version that does not requires South. Just for reference, how do you wrap a deletion in the .ebextension?

Comment: all documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html